# Calculate path and distance between points

Tags: java, geolocation, openstreetmap, distance

I'm writing application in Java. I have a list of lat long, and I want to convert it to path. Then calculate distance between points. And finally base on current location (lat, long) detect point on path, and calculate remaining distance to final point.

How can I do it, do you know any libraries that could help me?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What kind of libraries have you already looked for and found? A simple Google search finds http://www.geotools.org/ https://github.com/locationtech/spatial4j and https://java-source.net/open-source/geospatial, could any of these libraries help you?

Comment: This is offtopic to ask library here but for info, to calculate some distance, this depends on the limit of location, the distance between coordinates depends on the latitude since you are on a sphere. There is some formula on the net. For library, did you think about Google API ? There is API to do that already (limited on request per day/week/month for free usage)

Comment: Yes I think I can calculate by myself, so do you have such formula? But maybe to not invent the wheel I should use some library? It need to be free solution. I don't ask about library just for solution for described problem. In one of project we use graphhoper, but it's too big for this, maybe simple code would be enough

Answer (score 1):

When the points are not that far apart you can calculate the distance using the Pythagorean theorem. By calculating the distance between the points and adding them up you can get the total distance. (I assume that the points are sorted) I believe you also want to get the point on the path that is the closest to the current location. To do this you can use the same formular to check the distance for every point and use the shortest. If you have really many points you might want to use only every 10th point first to save time and resources.

I hope I could help you